# Java login to Aristotle Metadata Registry

Tags: java, python, django, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to write a Java app to query data in an Aristotle Metadata Registry instance. I eventually plan to query for entry points that provide JSON output for my app to work on. To get started I have to login to Aristotle. When I look at the Aristotle console for a regular web user logging in I see this sequence:

```
[15/Aug/2018 21:16:59] "GET /login?next=/account/home HTTP/1.1" 200 7098
[15/Aug/2018 21:16:59] "GET /static/COMPILED/aristotle_mdr/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 784
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /account/home HTTP/1.1" 200 16379
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/aristotle_mdr/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 122241
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/aristotle_mdr/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 37340
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/COMPILED/aristotle_mdr/aristotle.visuals.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1320
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/COMPILED/aristotle_mdr/aristotle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6957
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/aristotle_mdr/bootstrap.wcag.css HTTP/1.1" 200 656
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/aristotle_mdr/pink.wcag.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1231
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/aristotle_mdr/aristotle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1647
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/bootstrap3_datetime/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7785
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/bootstrap3_datetime/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 61317
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/bootstrap3_datetime/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 38514
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/aristotle_mdr/aristotle.notify.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3848
[15/Aug/2018 21:17:08] "GET /static/COMPILED/aristotle_mdr/aristotle.dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2506
```

I'm not trying to reproduce loading .js and .css, but trying to copy the other GETs and POSTs. My test program produces these results:

```
[15/Aug/2018 21:22:53] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 7085
[15/Aug/2018 21:22:53] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Aug/2018 21:22:53] "GET /account/home HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Aug/2018 21:22:53] "GET /login?next=/account/home HTTP/1.1" 200 7098
```

Not only is something different here, but the HTML returned is not "account/home" for my test user but is a fresh login page.

From research online I'm saving and using cookies from my server calls, in particular "csrftoken" and "csrfmiddlewaretoken". These values sometimes change from request to response. I suspect I may not be managing these correctly. I also wonder about other cookies that I see when I follow the web login, such as "sessionid", "JSESSIONID", "remember-me", and "XSRF-TOKEN". I've also debugged the Aristotle server. I can follow the request.user from the web, but my test program shows as "Anonymous-User". I must be missing something to retain the user.

The test program is definitely not proper for real login and security. Right now I'm just trying to get past login so I can explore how to request data. I'd appreciate any ideas. Test program follows.

```
package tester;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AristotleConnect {

    private CookieManager msCookieManager = new CookieManager();
    private String fullCookieString;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AristotleConnect ac = new AristotleConnect();
        ac.connect();
    }

    private void connect() {
        String urlStr = "http://localhost:8000/";
        String loginUrlStr = urlStr + "login";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        // Initial connection
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(loginUrlStr).openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Save cookies
        saveCookies(connection);

        // Try login
        String user = "SOME-REAL-USER";
        String pw = "THE-PASSWORD";
        String params = "username=" + user + "&password=" + pw;

        try {
            sendPost(loginUrlStr, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//      // Does resaving cookies now give us what we need for login?
//      saveCookies(connection);
//      try {
//          sendPost(loginUrlStr, params);
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }


    }

    private void saveCookies(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";

        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
        List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);
        fullCookieString = cookiesHeader.get(0);

        if (cookiesHeader != null) {
            for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
                msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null,HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
            }               
        }
    }

    private String addCookie(HttpURLConnection con, String urlParameters) {
        String newUrlParameters = urlParameters;
        if (msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {

            con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", fullCookieString );

            String csrfValue = "";
            for ( HttpCookie ck : msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
                if ( "csrftoken".equals(ck.getName())) {
                    csrfValue = ck.getValue();
                }
            }
            newUrlParameters = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + csrfValue + "&" + newUrlParameters ;
            con.setRequestProperty("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfValue);

        }
        return newUrlParameters;
    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private HttpURLConnection sendPost(String url, String urlParameters) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

        urlParameters = addCookie(con, urlParameters);

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Show results
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + con.getURL());
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

        return con;
    }
}
```